# Unix Signal handling in Qt Embedded Linux

Tags: usb-drive, qt, embedded-system, signal

I have an application for the USB interface in Qt (Embedded Linux).

When a pen-drive is inserted, the kernel sends a signal for that and I want to recognize that signal and I want my Qt application to detect it.

I went through the UNIX signal handling tutorial of Qt but i could not find any way of my problem.

I implemented the same thing as done in the tutorial but i did not find the way to detect the pen-drive. It only kills the processes.

Please go through the following link.

[Qt Unix Signal Handling](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/unix-signals.html)

I have also found using QdBus library of qt. I cross compiled it but gave me the errors of lidbus version.

Is there any other way to detect the external pendrive from the application ?

Comment: OK i got the solution.Actually busybox provides a mkdev utility. through this utility i have used the udev and connect detect the signal from my qt application.